# About approximating derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function. Using the definition of derivative, we approximate $f′(s)$ as follows.
For $|s-1|$ small, we have $f′(s)≃(f(s²-s+1)-f(s))/(s-1)²$, then $f(1)=lim_{s→1}f′(s)=lim_{s→1}(f(s²-s+1)-f(s))/(s-1)²$

I want to find zeros of $f′(s)=0$.

My **question** is as follow:

Is it true that the zeros of $f′(s)$ are the same zeros of $f(s²-s+1)-f(s)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. Did you even try a single example? If $f(s) = s^2$, then $f'$ has a zero at $s=0$ and nowere else. On the other hand

$$f(s^2-s+1)-f(s) = s^4 - 2s^3 + 2s^2 - 2s + 1$$

which has zeros at $\pm1, \pm i$.

(An even simpler example is $f(s) = s$, but then $f'$ is zero-free.)